# iPOJO manipulation for OSGi bundles in Eclipse Bndtools

Tags: java, osgi, bndtools, ipojo

I want to use iPOJO annotations for component declaration in Eclispe and have the iPOJO manipulation to be done to include the 'iPOJO-Components' header in the bundle manifest during the build.

After googling I came to know a little about 'bnd-ipojo-plugin'. I do not know whether this can solve the problem.

I want to know :

1) whether this can solve my problem.
2)  if it can solve the problem , how do I add the this 'bnd-ipojo-plugin' to the 'cnf' directory.

Please help solve the problem